# Mysql database migration failing on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have this migration file:

```
class InitialDigitizationWork < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :digitizations do |t|
      t.string :submission_code, :null => false
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :digitizations, :submission_code, :unique => true

    create_table :digitized_pieces do |t|
      t.integer :digitization_id, :null => false
      t.integer :position, :null => false
      t.string :piece_type, :default => "Page"
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :digitized_pieces, :digitization_id

    create_table :digitized_views do |t|
      t.integer :digitized_piece_id, :null => false
      t.string :initial_file_name
      t.string :attachment_file_name
      t.string :attachment_content_type
      t.integer :attachment_file_size
      t.datetime :attachment_updated_at
      t.integer :position, :null => false
      t.boolean :is_primary, :default => false
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :digitized_views, :digitized_piece_id, :null => false
  end
```

and it fails on the last line:

```
-- add_index(:digitized_views, :digitized_piece_id, {:null=>false})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Unknown key: :null. Valid keys are: :unique, :order, :name, :where, :length, :internal, :using, :algorithm,
```

Anyone have any idea what is going on?

What's annoying here is that since the last line fails, I can't rerun the migration again because the table on top `digitizations` exists. I know how to use Postgresql and access the specific table that is created specified by this `yml` file:

```
#SQLite version 3.x
 #gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard)

development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: arthouse_development
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
  #socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

legacy_development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: arthouse_legacy_development
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
```

Anyone know how I can console into the database here?

Anyone know what might be going on? This is my first time using `mysql` and could use some help.

also when I type in `mysql` this happens:

```
 mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jwan'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

but this works:

```
mysql -u root
```

Do I have to do that everytime?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is what you need to do:

First rollback your last migration so that you begin on a clean slate:

```
rake db:rollback
```

Then remove the `default=> null` constraint on your indexes. The error message states explicitly that it's not a known `key`:

> Unknown key: :null. Valid keys are: :unique, :order, :name, :where,
>   :length, :internal, :using, :algorithm,

Then rerun the migration:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: How did this wind up here then in the first place? I just pulled down this codebase. Any theories as to how this got here?

Comment: Sorry not understanding what you mean. What’s up?

Comment: Like.... Production works for this codebase. So how did this migration wind up in here?